# How to check if enum value exists in a list of objects

Tags: java, list, enums

I have enum and I have no trouble iterating over its values like this:

```
for(catType ct : catType.values()) {
        if(ct.toString().equals()))
}
```

I have List of objects where every object has(or does not have) a property matching the values from the enum.

```
List<Zoo> zoos = zooRepository.findAll();
```

To get a String I need from first index of zoos I must

```
zoos.get(0).getAnimal();
```

How can I iterate over all catTypes so I can check if they exist in any object from the List of objects, so if they don't exist there I can further add them to the database?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but it seems like you need maps where the enums are the keys - or you just iterate over all animals and check their cat type, e.g. by creating a set of all possible types and removing those the animals have, what's left in the end is what's missing.

Comment: @Thomas I need to iterate over both the enum values and every object from the list and to catch if there is a value that exists in the enum but does not exist in any of the objects from the list. Your approach looks legit and I will give it a try !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using java8, it can be done via lambda expression

```
for(catType ct : catType.values()) {
     boolean exist = zoos.stream()
        .anyMatch(zoo -> zoo.getAnimal().equals(ct.toString()));
```

}

Comment: If you create a Set<String> prior to the for-loop then you can perform the inclusion checks with `contains` instead of repetitively streaming a (potentially very large) list of animals.